# What use is setInterval with a value of zero?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have seen some JavaScript code that has the following:

```
var myFunc = function () { 
    timeout = setTimeout(myFunc, 0); 
}
```

It seems that this would immediately recall the function.

What use case is there for this?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4575011/453277 (which I think explains it better).

Comment: how is this a duplicate if the other questions were about setTimeout, which is NOT the same as setInterval? i've not thought of using setInterval(f,0), so it seems like a new concept to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/779785/2612112)

In short, it "pauses" the JavaScript execution to let the rendering threads catch up. It gives the browser a chance to finish doing some none-JavaScript things that have been waiting to finish before attending to this new piece of JavaScript.

Comment: did you vote to close as a duplicate? I think you should.

Comment: Not useful. You are merely restating what the duplicate (now officially closed as such) says. The correct approach is to vote to close.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah, I'll do that next time.